# How is the list of questions for Tour page populated?

Tags: support, questions, moderator-tools, tour

Moderators are able to [edit the question](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/admin/about/choose-question) that will be shown on Tour page, but that list is quite short.

How is that list populated? Expected criteria are:

- has high positive score
- has several answers
- has accepted answer

But there are obviously a lot more questions on site with such criteria.